# Vue.js: Property or method is not defined on the instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a simple vue component:

```js
Vue.component('repo-button', {
  props:["check_in_id", "repo_id"],
  template: '#repo-button',
  methods: {
    fetchRepo: function() {
      console.log("this is working")
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    var that = this;
    return {}
  }
});

var repositionings = new Vue({
    el: "#repo-vue"
})
```

And my view looks like:

```html
<script type="text/x-template" id="repo-button">
    <div class='socialCircle-item success'>
    <i class='fa fa-comment' 
      :data-check_in='check_in_id' 
      :data-repo='repo_id'> 
    </i>
    </div>
</script>

<div id="repo-vue">
    <div is="repo-button" repo_id="8" check_in_id="30" @click="fetchRepo></div>
</div>
```

and I see the error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "fetchRepo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

It seems like I have registered the method, but it's looking in the root component for the method when I think it should be an instance method. 
 **How am I supposed to include the `fetchRepo` instance method?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `fetchRepo` as a method of your component, but you are trying to call it from *outside* the component.

Move the click handler inside your component.

```html
<script type="text/x-template" id="repo-button">
    <div class='socialCircle-item success' @click="fetchRepo">
    <i class='fa fa-comment' 
      :data-check_in='check_in_id' 
      :data-repo='repo_id'> 
    </i>
    </div>
</script>

<div id="repo-vue">
    <div is="repo-button" repo_id="8" check_in_id="30"></div>
</div>
```